# In app purchase with Automatic Reference Couting: SKProductsRequestDelegate crashes

Tags: objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase, automatic-ref-counting

I've now been trying for two days to implement in app purchase in an iOS app, with the same error bugging me.

I get an EXC_BAC_ACCESS error every time I try to start my SKProductsRequest object.

I've read dozens of people having me same error, but none of the solutions seems to work for me.

When I set NSZombieEnabled, i get following error:

```
[AppShopper respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1d9340
```

Here's my AppShopper.h:

```
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

#define kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification @"kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification"


@interface AppShopper : NSObject <SKProductsRequestDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) SKProduct *product;
@property (nonatomic, strong) SKProductsRequest *request;

- (void) requestProductData;

@end
```

And my AppShopper.m:

```
#import "AppShopper.h"

@implementation AppShopper

#define productId @"XXX.ProductID.XXX"

@synthesize request = _request;
@synthesize product = _product;

- (void) request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    printf("Error!\n");
    _request = nil;
    _product = nil;
}

- (void) requestDidFinish:(SKRequest *)request {
    printf("Finished request!\n");
}

- (void) requestProductData{
    printf("requestProductData\n");

    NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:productId];

    self.request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers: productIdentifiers];

    self.request.delegate = self;
    [self.request start];

    printf("requestProductData End\n");
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SKProductsRequestDelegate methods

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    printf("productsRequest\n");
    NSArray *products = response.products;

    self.product = [products count] == 1 ? [products objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    if (self.product)
    {
        NSLog(@"Product title: %@" , self.product.localizedTitle);
        NSLog(@"Product description: %@" , self.product.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"Product price: %@" , self.product.price);
        NSLog(@"Product id: %@" , self.product.productIdentifier);
    }

    for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
    {
        NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
    }

    _request = nil;
    _product = nil;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification object:self userInfo:nil];
}


@end
```

I try to start the in app purchase with the following code:

```
AppShopper *shopper = [[AppShopper alloc] init];
[shopper requestProductData];
```

My output is only:

```
requestProductData
requestProductData End

2012-09-10 19:43:30.210 MyApp[4327:707] *** -[AppShopper respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1d9340
```

And, yes I am:

1. testing on a physical device
2. in sandbox environment with test user
3. with a proper provisioning profile

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug will be in whichever object makes your `AppShopper`.

For example,

```
AppShopper *shopper = [AppShopper new];
... setup shopper here ...
[shopper requestProductData];
```

How does ARC know that you want to keep your `AppShopper` around? It doesn't and it will release it immediately after `requestProductData`. Then, when the request returns it will try to call it's delegate methods, which won't exist anymore.

Try storing your `AppShopper` as a strong property instead of a local variable and see if that helps.

Comment: It's really annoying - `NSURLConnection` retains it's delegate during a connection but `SKProductsRequest` doesn't :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all, add these functions in

In AppShopper.m

```
//Checks if the device or user can make purchases
- (BOOL)canMakePurchases
{
    return [SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments];
}
```

File from which you call, initiate the inApp purchase in this way

```
AppShopper *shopper = [[AppShopper new];
if([shopper canMakePurchases])
{
    [shopper requestProductData];
}
```