# how to set product in paymentwithproduct in ios7

Tags: ios7, in-app-purchase

App crashes with error

> [SKProduct productIdentifier]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x16d574f0

after in `.h` file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>
#define kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification @"kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification"
#define kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionFailedNotification @"kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionFailedNotification"
#define kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionSucceededNotification @"kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionSucceededNotification"
    @interface InAppPurchaseManager : NSObject <SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver> {
    SKProduct *proUpgradeProduct;
    SKProductsRequest *productsRequest;

}
@property (retain, nonatomic) SKProduct *proUpgradeProduct;
@property (retain, nonatomic) SKProductsRequest *productsRequest;


// Public Methods
-(void)loadStore;
-(BOOL)canMakePurchases;
-(void)purchaseProUpgrade;
-(void)restorePurchases;
-(void)requestProUpgradeProductData;

@end
```

my functions is:

```
- (NSString *)productIdentifier {
    return kInAppPurchaseProUpgradeProductId;
}

// Contacting the App Store for the available products
-(void)requestProUpgradeProductData {
    NSLog(@"Getting Product");

    NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:kInAppPurchaseProUpgradeProductId];
    productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [productsRequest start];

}

// Retreiving all products and informing you of any invalid products
// Invalid products include those not approved by Apple
-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

    productsRequest=nil;
    NSArray *products = response.products;

    proUpgradeProduct = [[[SKProduct alloc]init] autorelease];

    proUpgradeProduct = [products count] == 1 ? [products firstObject]: nil;
    if (proUpgradeProduct) {
        NSLog(@"Product title: %@", proUpgradeProduct.localizedTitle);
        NSLog(@"Product description: %@", proUpgradeProduct.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"Product price: %@", proUpgradeProduct.price);
        NSLog(@"Product id: %@", proUpgradeProduct.productIdentifier);
    }

    for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers) {
        NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@", invalidProductId);
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification object:self userInfo:nil];
}

- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"Failed to load list of products.");
    proUpgradeProduct = nil;


}

// Call this method once on startup
-(void)loadStore {
    NSLog(@"Loading Store");

    // Restarts any purchases if they were interrupted last time the app was open
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

    // Get the product description
    [self requestProUpgradeProductData];

}

// Call this before making a purchase
-(BOOL)canMakePurchases {
    return [SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments];
}


// Called when user wants to purchase the product
-(void)purchaseProUpgrade {

    //NSArray *products = productsRequest.;


    SKPayment *payment = [[SKPayment alloc] init];


    NSLog(@"%@", proUpgradeProduct);
   // NSLog(@"Purchasing Product %@", proUpgradeProduct.productIdentifier);
    payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:proUpgradeProduct];



    //[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

}

// Restores previously purchsed products
-(void)restorePurchases {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];

}
```

my controller code

```
-(IBAction)buyUpgrade {

    [inAppPurchaseManager purchaseProUpgrade];

    // Add a notification observer to tell us when the purchase has been completed.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(purchaseComplete:) name:kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionSucceededNotification object:nil];


}

-(void)purchaseComplete:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionSucceededNotification]) {
        NSLog(@"Purchase Successful!");
        // Notify user of successful purchase if desired
    }
}
```

and load store in controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    inAppPurchaseManager = [[InAppPurchaseManager alloc] init];

    [inAppPurchaseManager loadStore];

    [inAppPurchaseManager canMakePurchases];

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isProUpgradePurchased"]) {
        // Product has been purchased
        // Show premium options
        //
        //

    } else {
        // Product has not been purcahsed
        // Show free options
        //
        //
    }
    }
```

controller.h file

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {

    InAppPurchaseManager *inAppPurchaseManager;


}

-(IBAction)buyUpgrade;

@end
```

log file

```
Relax[4469:60b] Loading Store
Relax[4469:60b] Getting Product
Relax[4469:60b] <Google> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"fb34c5", nil];
Relax[4469:60b] Product title: Full Sounds Pack
Relax[4469:60b] Product description: The Full Sounds Pack includes all sounds, ads removal and every sound that will be added in the future
Relax[4469:60b] Product price: 1.79
Relax[4469:60b] <Google:HTML> Google Mobile Ads SDK: You are currently using 6.4.2 of the SDK. A new version, 6.8.0, is available at http://goo.gl/Zc0BYt . Please consider updating your SDK to get the latest features and bug fixes
Relax[4469:60b] *** -[SKProduct respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x145cec70
```

Where is the problem with `proUpgradeProduct` is null???

Comment: Can you give the log output generated by your program?

Comment: *** -[SKProduct productIdentifier]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x15deb470

Comment: So, it sounds like didReceiveResponse is not being called. Can you please show the value of proUpgradeProduct immediately before the line SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:proUpgradeProduct]; ? That is, put an NSLog(@"%@", proUpgradeProduct); before that line.

Comment: add log and chrash app in log line

log:
-[SKProduct respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x155d75c0

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding you. Please edit your original post to show your revised code, with the log message that I suggested.

Comment: ok edit my post and add more code! I hope now became a little clearer

Comment: Why do you have the line "[self dealloc];"? I believe you should never call dealloc explicitly. Get rid of this.

Comment: edit my post again and remove this, was wrong sorry!

Comment: What is the log output of your program now?

Comment: [SKProduct respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x155ca970

Comment: I think you are not giving enough information to solve your problem. Perhaps not enough program code? I need to know the execution flow of your program. The loadStore method is not getting called?

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    inAppPurchaseManager = [[InAppPurchaseManager alloc] init];
    
    [inAppPurchaseManager loadStore];
    
    [inAppPurchaseManager canMakePurchases];
    
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isProUpgradePurchased"]) {
        // Product has been purchased
        // Show premium options
        //
        //

    } else {
        // Product has not been purcahsed
        // Show free options
        //
        //
    }

Comment: I'm afraid you are going to have to find someone else to help you. There seems to be a basic communication problem here. I can't even tell if the loadStore method is being called.

Comment: If loadStore was getting called, we should see log output for that, right?

Comment: You should have given this to me when I asked for your log output earlier! Please put this log output in your original post so it's not so hard to read. Please put the *entire* log output.

Comment: Why are you setting productsRequest=nil; at the start of the didReceiveResponse method? I'm not quite sure what the effect of deallocating your request will be prior to completing the didReceiveResponse method. I'd take that out.

Comment: remove productsRequest=nil; and the problem is exactly the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem where proUpgradeProduct is null located in the line

```
proUpgradeProduct = [products count] == 1 ? [products firstObject]: nil;
```

I realized that it must be as follows

```
proUpgradeProduct = [products count] == 1 ? [[products firstObject] retain]: nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you working from this [In app purchase with Automatic Reference Couting: SKProductsRequestDelegate crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351400/in-app-purchase-with-automatic-reference-couting-skproductsrequestdelegate-cras) code?

It seems like your proUpgradeProduct is being deallocated. I can't see how though. I'd clean up the code some to simplify. For example, I'd get rid of the proUpgradeProduct and productsRequest properties (or the instance variables). I'd also get rid of the line:

proUpgradeProduct = [[[SKProduct alloc]init] autorelease];

in didReceiveResponse. It's doing nothing useful.

When you make changes in the code, please make sure to exactly copy the changed methods the posted code.

Comment: add in post viewcontroller.h file.